# Unable to iterate over the stream created (second time) with Steam.spliterator on an Iterable

Tags: java, java-stream, spliterator

I am unable to unable to iterate (second time) over the stream created with Steam.spliterator . I could not find documentation about the same.

Here is what i am doing:

I got a `Iterable` as funciton argument and I am iterating this via stream like following code :

```
StreamSupport.stream(values.spliterator(), false)
```

and following that i am doing it again but the second one do not iterate at all. I spent lot of time debugging it and finally converted the iterable to a list in the beginning itself.

Do any of you guys know the reason ?

Edit: Sorry if i am not clear ,

I was not using the stream multiple times , I was generating the stream in the above way with the same Iterable.

Iterable is the one coming from reduce in MapReduce job.

Thanks,
Hareendra

Comment: You can only ever use a `Stream`, and therefore a `Spliterator`, once; that is why

Comment: Are you using the same iterator object or generating a new one?

Comment: I have the Iterable (in above example values) .
which i am creating a stream with StreamSupport.stream(values.spliterator(), false)

Comment: Be more specific about the type of the `Iterable`.

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

A `Stream` is a one-shot object. You can consume it only once, not multiple times. If you want to use the contents multiple times you have to do like you did, converting the stream to a list or array or anything non-streamy and then create two new streams out of it for the two things you want to do.

Quote from [JavaDoc of `Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) class:

> A stream should be operated on (invoking an intermediate or terminal stream operation) only once. This rules out, for example, "forked" streams, where the same source feeds two or more pipelines, or multiple traversals of the same stream.

Comment: So? At least your title is wrong which says you use `Stream.spliterator()` that means to me `values` is a `Stream` and thus cannot be used twice.

Comment: Not really. You still say you call `Stream.splitarator()` so is `values` a stream or not? if it is an `Iterable` then please fix your post.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the `Iterable` instance you are using to create your `Spliterator` truly honors the `Iterable` contract.  Some people make the mistake of thinking that anything that implements `iterator()` will serve as an `Iterable`, and that is not the case. To comply with the `Iterable` contract, one must be able to call `iterator()` multiple times and be able to iterate with it each time.

Because it is very easy to create an `Iterable` from anything that has an `iterator()` function, I have seen several cases of a manufactured `Iterable` exhibiting the behavior you mention.  For example, one can do this:

```
Stream<String> stream = ...
Iterable<String> falseIterable = stream::iterator;
```

`falseIterable` does not follow required `Iterable` semantics because `falseIterable.iterator()`, being a wrapper around `stream.iterator()`, will not return a usable `Iterator` a second time, once it has been iterated over.